# Running Jmeter script through jenkins Out of Memory error while generating report

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter, out-of-memory, jenkins-plugins

I am facing an Out of Memory issue while running Jmeter script through Jenkins.The process is there is code written in framework that will convert the generated XML file result to CSV then HTML to Publish the report in dashboard.

I have already tried Increasing Heap space pf Jenkins server to 25 GB out of 32 GB.It seems Initially it takes 1 Gb then after some times it throws the error even though it still have 24 GB pf memory available in heap ,I ran free -h for this.

Also tried increasing Jmeter memory by 
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m

The script executed fine in Jnekins server which is on Windows.But it throsw error when the jenkin server is on Linux mode.

Hear is my error log.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Resources/csvReportPath/ITT2_Unicast_Broker_Download_count.xml/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Resources//Configuration/transformGaurav.xsl/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/jmeter_reports/ITT2_Unicast_Broker_Download_2_Oct_2019_19_3_52_Count.html{titleReport=ITT2_Unicast_Broker_DownloadCountReport, dateReport=2-Oct-2019 22:02:38}
Finished Parsing
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Resources/csvReportPath/AutomationReport_5.2.4.2018.20_2_Oct_2019_19_3_52_count.xml/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Resources//Configuration/transformGaurav.xsl/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/jmeter_reports/AutomationReport_5.2.4.2018.20_2_Oct_2019_19_3_52.html{titleReport=nullCountReport, dateReport=2-Oct-2019 22:02:39}
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2019/10/02 18:33:10 - please wait.
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2019/10/02 18:33:10 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/heapdump.20191002.183310.40181.0001.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/heapdump.20191002.183310.40181.0001.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/core.20191002.183310.40181.0002.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I System dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/core.20191002.183310.40181.0002.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/javacore.20191002.183310.40181.0003.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/javacore.20191002.183310.40181.0003.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Snap.20191002.183310.40181.0005.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Snap.20191002.183310.40181.0005.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/heapdump.20191002.183310.40181.0004.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/heapdump.20191002.183310.40181.0004.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/javacore.20191002.183310.40181.0006.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/javacore.20191002.183310.40181.0006.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Snap.20191002.183310.40181.0007.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ITT2_Execution/Snap.20191002.183310.40181.0007.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.xerces.xni.XMLString.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.characters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanCharReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at utils.APIReportProcessing.fetchAPIReportDetailModuleWise(APIReportProcessing.java:110)
    at jmeterRun.RunProcess.prepareFinalResultsMerged(RunProcess.java:228)
    at jmeterRun.ControllerJMeter.main(ControllerJMeter.java:139)
    ... 6 more
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
```

Thanks
Bibek

Answer (score 0):

The JMeter process runs in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) under various settings and arguments. The Java Heap Space (as referred to in the error message) is the memory the JVM takes from the underlying operating system to allocate space for the creation of necessary objects.

JMeter’s default configuration (see jmeter.bat for Windows or jmeter for non-Windows systems scripts) assumes a heap space of 512 megabytes only. This is actually pretty low considering  many modern smartphones have up to four times more! If your test is running massive objects which go over 512Mb, you’ll get an OOM error and your test will fail.

Fortunately, there’s a simple solution. Just increase the maximum heap size to ~80% of your total available physical RAM. To do this, find the following line in your JMeter startup script:

> HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx25g"

Now change the -Xmx value accordingly. For example: if you want to set the maximum heap size to 25 gigabytes, you’ll need to change the line to:

> HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx25g"

To apply the change, you’ll need to restart JMeter.

Comment: Hi @SAIR Thanks for your reply. I already increase the Heap memory of Jmeter and Jenkins by the process you mentioned and it's still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Understand the OutOfMemoryError Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) article:

> **Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
>
> Cause: The detail message Java heap space indicates object could not be allocated in the Java heap. This error does not necessarily imply a memory leak. The problem can be as simple as a configuration issue, where the specified heap size (or the default size, if it is not specified) is insufficient for the application.
>   In other cases, and in particular for a long-lived application, the message might be an indication that the application is unintentionally holding references to objects, and this prevents the objects from being garbage collected. This is the Java language equivalent of a memory leak. Note: The APIs that are called by an application could also be unintentionally holding object references.
>
> One other potential source of this error arises with applications that make excessive use of finalizers. If a class has a finalize method, then objects of that type do not have their space reclaimed at garbage collection time. Instead, after garbage collection, the objects are queued for finalization, which occurs at a later time. In the Oracle Sun implementation, finalizers are executed by a daemon thread that services the finalization queue. If the finalizer thread cannot keep up, with the finalization queue, then the Java heap could fill up and this type of OutOfMemoryError exception would be thrown. One scenario that can cause this situation is when an application creates high-priority threads that cause the finalization queue to increase at a rate that is faster than the rate at which the finalizer thread is servicing that queue.
>
> Action: You can find more information about how to monitor objects for which finalization is pending in [Monitor the Objects Pending Finalization.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks004.html#CIHCDBJB)

So use [Java Memory Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) tool to investigate the largest objects and what process do they belong to.

Also it appears you're running Jenkins on Linux or other Unix-like os while [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command is Windows-specific. In addition Jenkins doesn't respect `HEAP` environment variable, it uses `JAVA_ARGS` and/or `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead.

For JMeter:

```
HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx8g" && export HEAP
```

For Jenkins:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1g -Xmx8g" && export JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

More information:

- [How to add Java arguments to Jenkins?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/)